# what does >> do in c++

Tags: c++

i'm going through google university section on c++ and i'm not sure what this piece of code does:

```
if (!(cin >> input_var)) {

    cout << "you entered a non-numeric. Exiting..." << endl;
    break;

}
```

What does the statement inside the if statement actually do here?

thanks!

Comment: Depends.. what's the type of input_var?

Comment: If the input the user entered is not compatible with the type of "input_var"... Is what it means

Comment: I'm sorry, I have to get this off my chest. So you're going through Google university and you couldn't Google that by yourself? That's a very basic question. Self-learning has never been easy, and people are just getting lazier and lazier.

Comment: guys... the statement inside the `if` statement is `{ cout << "you entered a non-numeric. Exiting... << endl; break; }`.  It's a compound statement.  The controlling expression `!(cin >> input_var)` everyone is talking about isn't a statement at all.

Comment: @BenVoigt The question title suggests that he means "expression". :D

Comment: @sftrabbit: Yes, probably so.  But how's he going to learn the correct terminology when everyone goes and abuses it along with him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cin >> input_var` prompts the user for an input which is saved in the `input_var`. If the input is received other than integers then it goes inside the if condition.
"Considering the variable is an int."

Answer (score 7):

This is very basic C++. Typically, `>>` and `<<` are used for bit shifting. However, the I/O stream library has overloaded `operator>>` and `operator<<` for streams so that they can be used for *extraction* and *insertion* respectively. Why? Because the operator looks like two arrows that have some directionality and so the code reads nicely - data is moving in that direction.

So in your example, `cin` is the standard input stream and you are extracting an integer from that stream into the variable `input_var`. You read `cin >> input_var` as "extract `input_var` from the standard input".

Similarly, inside the body of your `if` statement, you are inserting into the standard output stream, `cout`.

The I/O overloads for `operator<<` and `operator>>` return a reference to the stream you're extracting from or inserting into. This stream is convertible to `bool` to allow you to check its status. That is, doing `if (cin)` will check if the status of the `cin` stream is okay. In your case, we are using the "not" operator, `!`, to check if the stream is *not* okay. If it's not, we output the error.

It's worth mentioning that the `!(cin >> input_var)` inside the `if` statement is not a statement itself - it's an expression.

Comment: +1, but I wouldn't call this *very* basic C++.  It's fundamental syntax, sure.  But many programmers will never need to shift bits, so they may not get exposure to this syntax.

Comment: @JohnDibling I think people tend to be exposed to extraction and insertion before they are exposed to bit shifting (in fact, it's usually in the first example taught). That's what I meant was very basic.

Answer (score 3):

It reads an `int` (the variable `input_var`) and checks if the read was succesful via the `!(cin >> ...)` part (`istream` has an overloaded `operator !`).

Comment: so it attempts to store the value read into input_var and if it is not successful it enters the if statement which causes the program to break out of the loop?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( !(cin >> input_var) )
```

Here `>>` is an operator overloaded for `std::istream&`, and based on the type of `input_var` a specific overload is called which reads data from the stream and stores in `input_var`. The operator overload return type is `std::istream&`, which means the type of the expression `cin >> input_var` is `std::istream&` which, when used in `if` or `while`, can *automatically* convert into `true` or `false` depending on whether the read-from-the-stream was succeeded or not. So you can write this in any construct which requires boolean expression, such as `if` and `while`.

```
if ( cin >> data )
{
     //this block will execute only if the data was successfully read
}
```

Similarly,

```
while ( cin >> data )
{
     //this block will execute only if the data was successfully read
     //and the loop will continue until read attempt fails.
}
```

Comment: There's no implicit conversion in the code in the question.  istream's `operator!` is used.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21336/discussion-between-ben-voigt-and-nawaz)

Answer (score 1):

In the context of iostreams, writers often will refer to << and >> as the “put-to” or "stream insertion" and “get-from” or "stream extraction" operators, respectively.

If you use >> between operands that means its Bitwise right shift

Comment: *"If you use >> between operands that means its Bitwise right shift"*? I believe the word "integer" is missing somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The `>>` operator takes on two meanings, depending on context.

It can be a right shift operator, when using integers: `1024 >> 3` performs a bit shift.

In your case, you would consider it the "extraction operator". When extracting from `cin`, the program reads from standard input (generally the keyboard) and tries to format it as something that fits in the right hand side. Since you're reading into an integer, it would perform the following steps:

- Read and discard any preceding whitespace
- Read and interpret a `+` or `-` as a positive or negative sign
- Read as many numeric characters as possible to build an integer.

If if can read something and make an integer, the process ends up returning something that evaluates to true, so the line:

```
if(!(cin >> input_var))
```

Checks to see if the conversion succeeded. If it couldn't read a number, say you entered `fred` instead, the process would return something that evaluates to false, since the conversion failed. The value returned is actually `cin`, which is convertible to `bool`, but that's a little down in the weeds.

Answer (score 0):

This is an overloaded operator.

- for input, extraction operator as `cin>>value;`
- for bitwise-right shift `value>>2;`

Answer (score 0):

It is an operator. The behaviour depends on the input_var. Have a look here: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).